# Alternatives of goto in my C++ console application

Tags: c++, c

I've recently got to a point where I had to deal with some logic in a C++ project, and unfortunately I was not able to do it right using `goto`.

*What was the problem about ?*

I have one function, named `ProcessRunning(const char *name)` which verifies if a process exists (it returns `true`) or not (it returns `false`).

I have another 4 functions, `int fun1(const char name[])`,`int fun2(const char name[])`,`int fun3(const char name[])`, `int fun4(const char name[])`.
 - each of these functions looks like this:

```
int fun1(const char name[]){
    //open a new .bat file

    //start of what I write in .bat

    //taskkill  process.exe
    //start again process.exe
    //delete the created file

    //end of what I write in the file
    return system(name);
}
```

And exactly the same for the other 3 functions.

Now, in my `main()` program I am trying to do the following:

```
int main(){
    //...
    start_again:
    if(ProcessRunning("process1.exe")){
        fun1("fun1.bat");
        goto start_again;
    }
    else if(ProcessRunning("process2.exe")){
        fun1("fun2.bat");
        goto start_again;
    }
    else if(ProcessRunning("process3.exe")){
        fun1("fun3.bat");
        goto start_again;
    }
    else if(ProcessRunning("process4.exe")){
        fun1("fun4.bat");
        goto start_again;
    }
    else if(!ProcessRunning("process1.exe") || !ProcessRunning("process2.exe") || !ProcessRunning("process3.exe") || !ProcessRunning("process4.exe") || ){
        goto start_again;
    }
    goto start_again;
    return 0;
}
```

Now what I would like the whole program to do:

- the program **MUST** always run;
- it checks if one of those 4 processes are running;
- if there's no such process, go back and check again (so there's a permanent check if any of those conditions aren't satisfied)
- if it finds `process1` (the first if), it creates that .bat file and it executes it (kill the first process, start it again, delete the `.bat` file).
  The process is now running, but the program should still go through the other `if`s and check if there's `process2`, `process3` or `process4` running and do the same thing for them.

Every process is assigned to an application, let's say:

app1 -> goes with `process1`
app2 -> goes with `process2`
..
app4 -> goes with `process4`

Cases:

- process1 is running
- process1 is not running
  ..
- and so on
  For the sake of example I'll just take `process1` but this should apply to all of them.

Because the app is always running, it checks if there's process1. If there isn't, it checks for process2 and if none is found, start over again and again. Otherwise, if process1 is found, do what's in that `if` condition but still look after the other processes.

Now, the problem that I have is that I can't find a better solution which will keep my console program running all the time and make these checks. More, the actual implementation that I've found so far it doesn't treat all those situations.

Any advices on this, please (improvements of logic, critiques, alternatives)? (sorry for the long post and possible grammar mistakes).

Comment: Sorry, wait, what was the problem? Is this just a code review request? If so, it's off-topic.

Comment: What is the purpose of any of the goto's other than the last one? Wouldn't that happen anyway?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was just trying to avoid the case in which I close `app1` and it reopens it instantly after this. It shall just keep looking for a process untill it appears

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check for the existance of each process every loop and you want to run forever you can use a while loop.

```
int main(){
    //...
    while(true) {
        if(ProcessRunning("process1.exe")){
            fun1("fun1.bat");
        }
        if(ProcessRunning("process2.exe")){
            fun1("fun2.bat");
        }
        if(ProcessRunning("process3.exe")){
            fun1("fun3.bat");
        }
        if(ProcessRunning("process4.exe")){
            fun1("fun4.bat");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We don't want to use `else if` here as we would never check another process if one process is found.  Using just `if` it will check each process each iteration.

EDIT:

From the comments it appears that you only want to run your function once.  To do that we can add a bool for each process and check that in the if condition.  if it is true then we will not run the function again.  To do that we can change the code to:

```
int main(){
    //...
    bool proc1 = false, proc2 = false, proc3 = false, proc4 = false,
    while(true) {
        if(!proc1 && ProcessRunning("process1.exe")){
            fun1("fun1.bat");
            proc1  = true;
        }
        if(!proc2 && ProcessRunning("process2.exe")){
            fun1("fun2.bat");
            proc2  = true;
        }
        if(!proc3 && ProcessRunning("process3.exe")){
            fun1("fun3.bat");
            proc3  = true;
        }
        if(!proc4 && ProcessRunning("process4.exe")){
            fun1("fun4.bat");
            proc4  = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now if `procX` is false then the we will check if the process is running and if it is we run `fun1()` then set `procX` to true.  Otherwise if `procX` is true the rest of the if statement is skipped.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. That fixed that specific case. Anyway, there's also the next situation: if `process1.exe` is running and I try to open the second process, that won't work. I mean, it won't close and reopen the second process. Any turnarounds for this too ?

Comment: @Alexander You might want to start a new question about this.  You can link back to this question to show where you started.

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868136/unsuccesfull-management-of-specific-processes-in-my-c-console-application

Comment: You will need a continue at the end of each if statement.

Comment: Otherwise it drops through into the next if instead of going back to the start.  Consequences of not using an else

Comment: @cup and that is what the OP wants.  they want to check each process each iteration.  just because their code does't do that doesn't mean mine is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about a map from String to String, in which the key is one string for the name of the process and the value is the .bat file to run? It will look elegant and scalable.

`std::map` is your friend!
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

With that, you could use the same `while` as the other answers, but if only one (or a just a couple of `if`s, even if you got a bazillion of possibilities.