# Unsuccesfull management of specific processes in my C++ console application

Tags: c++, c

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866306) I solved a part of my cases and thanks to NathanOliver I've got to the following code so far:

```
int main(){
    //...
    bool proc1 = false, proc2 = false, proc3 = false, proc4 = false,
    while(true) {
        if(!proc1 && ProcessRunning("process1.exe")){
            fun1("fun1.bat");
            proc1  = true;
        }
        if(!proc2 && ProcessRunning("process2.exe")){
            fun1("fun2.bat");
            proc2  = true;
        }
        if(!proc3 && ProcessRunning("process3.exe")){
            fun1("fun3.bat");
            proc3  = true;
        }
        if(!proc4 && ProcessRunning("process4.exe")){
            fun1("fun4.bat");
            proc4  = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I still can't get through is the case where:

- double click on app1 -> `process1` starts.
- while `process1` is running I double click on app2 so that `process2` should have the same behaviour as I mentioned in my first thread:

> if it finds `process2` (the second `if(){}`), it creates that .bat file and
>   it executes it (kill `process2`(it might existed before i opened it), start > it again, delete the `.bat` file generated by `fun2(const char name[]){}`).

---

*Summary of previous post:*

```
int fun1(const char name[]){
    ofstream file;
    file.open(name, ios::out);
    //start of what I write in .bat
    file << "@echo off";    
    file << "cd to specific path";
    file << "taskkill  /im process.exe* /f";
    file << "start process.exe";
    file << "del \"%~f0\"";

    file.close();
    return system(name);
}
```

Exactly the same for the rest functions.

Comment: Is your calling of `fun1` in all four cases a typo?

Comment: This is not going to work because proc1 is set to false and stays that way so far I can see in your code.

Comment: @molbdnilo No, each function has its own name. e.g: `function1`, ..., `function4` and each of them is called properly in my `main()`. I know the flags may be an issue but I've only been able to get so far using them

Answer (score 1):

I believe you run the .bat file as sync program, therefore until the bat won't finish and return exit code (which you may check as return value of system function) your main program won't continue to run. You may use async process using fork on linux based systems and CreateProcess on windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (C++11 Standard)

```
    bool proc[] = {false, false, false, false};

    while(true) 
    {
      for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
      {
        const std::string exeName = "process" + std::to_string(i) +  ".exe";            
        const std::string funName = "fun" + std::to_string(i) +  ".bat";            

        if(!proc[i] && ProcessRunning(exeName.c_str()))
        {
           fun1(funName.c_str());
           proc[i]  = true;
        }
    }
```

Should make things a bit more flexible, but getting to your problem. If-condition compares the first expression `proc` and then `ProcessRunning(...)`. Both must be true in order to enter the control block.

But your file explaining `fun1()` seems to have an issue at least in comments. You mention for example to `//taskkill  process.exe` but it has to be `process#`.

I can help you more on that if you provide the full `fun1` implementation or at least the most relevant parts. Your cycle though should work. The problem has to be in `fun1(...)`

P.D.: I also would rename `fun1(...)` to something that makes more sense.

Comment: I modified the `fun1` function so that it will make more sense to you now. Some misunderstands that you have: every function has different names ( I used fun1,2..just as a model) . Each function creates the same structure of `.bat` but the process each `.bat` handles is different.

Comment: But in the batch file you are referring as ``process.exe`` what you are trying to kill. So if you ask for ``process1.exe``. It won't be found. Try to create that batch file with the right process name. Also why do you rewrite the batch file every time you execute your app? What are you trying to do anyways with your programm? I think we need some explanation. It somehow seems that there is a better more elegant way to what you are trying to accomplish.